# UICoded Test: Window was closed but Exists property is still true, why?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

I'm using UI coded test on some application which has two window. The second one is opened from the 1st one.

When the second window is closed I expect that Window2.Exists property is false, but it's still true.

Why this is so? (Any ideas?)

Or how else I could be sure that 2nd window was successfully closed?